# Spring Security seems to be using a session even though I am using SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to secure an application using OAuth.  I wanted to make it stateless so I have a custom authentication filter that authenticates based on a token from the client.  My configuration for Spring Security is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
// require https
    http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/**").requiresSecure().and().portMapper().http(80).mapsTo(443);

    http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .cors().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(customOAuth2Filter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}
```

As you can see, I am using SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS which should mean that Spring Security never uses a session.  However, if I login and then try to access a protected endpoint without a token(say, if I close the tab and then open a protected endpoint in a new tab, or if I just refresh the page), the application will give me the data at the endpoint instead of asking me to login again.

So it seems like a session is being used even though I am using SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS.  However, I did notice that the JSESSIONID of each request being sent does not match the JSESSIONID in the set-cookie header of the previous response.  Not sure why that is or where the new JSESSIONID is coming from.

How do I make it so subsequent requests without the token will ask for login again?  Any insight into what is happening here would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `JSESSIONID` is nothing else but a cookie. Server-Browser communication are based on cookie. Server identify the browser using cookies.

Comment: Check whether `request.getSession(true)` is being called from somewhere.

Comment: As far as I've tested the JSESSIONID cookie is generated by spring's OAuth implementation, I've had the same problem and eventually I've created my own stateless 'OAuth' implementation.

Comment: how did you solved this problem ?